# Converting unix time to date time

Tags: angularjs, unix

I have this problem and solutions in other question dont help.

```
<td>{{mail.RecordTime}}</td>
```

and

```
<td>{{mail.RecordTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</td>
```

both give me unix time; `/Date(1512978120087)/`

when I try the other accepted answer as

```
<td>{{mail.RecordTime * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</td>
```

I get `0NaN-NaN-NaN NaN:NaN:NaN NaNNaN`

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does `mail.RecordTime` contain?

Comment: It's datetime on db, converts to Unixtime when I send it as Json to view.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bn34rs1/1/). The example works just fine.

Comment: I tried that before and said in my question that it doesnt work. You missed /Date(..)/ part around the unixtime sequence. Does it work with it too?